# Xamarin forms FormattedText binding not updating for uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio 2015 PCL with the following code to bind a Label FormattedText to a property in viewmodel and the property value changes when a button is selected.  This code works great in android but will not update in win 10.  I have not tried ios yet.  In win 10, when the label is valued initially it works fine but will not change when button selected.  I can see the property change and propertychanged fires but not update view.  Please let me know if my code is incorrect or this is a bug for win 10.  Thanks for your help.

`XAML
 <local:BindableLabel x:Name="labelInformation" Style="{StaticResourceLabelInformationStyle}" Height="{Binding InformationDisplayHeight}" FormattedText="{Binding InformationData}" IsVisible="{Binding VisibleInformation}"/>`

```
viewmodel
private FormattedString informationData;
public FormattedString InformationData
{
  get
  {
      return informationData;
}

  set
  {
    if (value != informationData)
    {
        informationData = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
    }
   }
}

private void InformationSelected()
{
   InformationData = informationFormattedString(informationString));
   VisibleInformation = true;
}

private FormattedString informationFormattedString(string string1)
{
    FormattedString formattedString = new FormattedString();

    //define formatted string using string1

     return formattedString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug in LabelRenderer for WinRT. As workaround you can use changing Label.Text property for updating FormattedText.
I tried to fix it in [my pull request](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/335/files)

Comment: This works perfectly. Completely fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try same binding on normal Label instead of your custom label, if it worked I think you have an issue on your custom label declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have already tried to use a Label instead of my custom label and I get the same results, no change in the label display text.  Also, I changed the FormattedText to Text and the FormattedString to string and it updates perfectly except of course the text is not formatted.

Comment: can you add a fixed height and width for your label , just for test the issue might be due to small height or width or both for the label.

Comment: I set the height and width (WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="2000") with BindableLabel and Label and I still get the same results. This problem is occurring on win 10 phone and desktop.